# PostgreSQL not installing on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL on my Ruby app, and am running into a problem. Whenever I'm trying to start my server I get an error stating:

`rescue in spec': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add gem 'pg' to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).`

which is weird because I've already added it to my Gemfile and ran `bundle install` and ran `bundle list` to check if it's been installed (which it is).

To run you through to what I've done.

I've started my PostgreSQL database, created a database and gave it a name & password.

Then I've changed the **database.yml** to:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

  # Important configs for cloud9, change password value
  # to what you entered in the previous psql step.
  template: template0 (not sure what the fill in here?)
  username: my_username (can be omitted)
  password: my_password (can be omitted)

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_database_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_database_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: my_database_production
  username: my_username
  password: <%= ENV['my_password'] %>
```

Then I added `gem 'pg'` to my **gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

gem 'rake'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'kramdown'
gem 'thor', '0.19.1'
gem 'spree_braintree_vzero', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_braintree_vzero'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development do
  gem 'pg'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'spree', '~> 3.1.0.rc1'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.1.0.rc1'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.1.0.rc1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'materialize-sass'
gem 'active_link_to'
gem 'mollie-api-ruby'
# gem 'spree_mollie', github: 'salman15/mollie_spree_2017', branch: 'stable'
gem 'spree_mollie', github: 'ttcremers/spree_mollie', branch: 'stable'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Then I try to start my server and get the following error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
```

**EDIT (10:12pm 31-01-18 CET)**

I'm running the app on Cloud9 (which is ubuntu), previous/current database is SQlite (Default), but now that I want to deploy the website it needs to be changed to a better database. Therefore PostgreSQL, current pg version is 1.0

Comment: Run `bundle show pg` and do you see the gem listed?

Comment: can you try adding  `gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'` to gemfile and bundle?

Comment: @imechemi It is on 1.0.0

Comment: I'll try, why 0.21 tho?

Comment: @AneesMuhammed I downgraded pg and it worked. Can you please write this as an answer so we can close this question?

Comment: @Salman I've posted the answer. Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, this a `pg` compatibility issue with your current rails version. There are many threads open here mentioning incompatibility of rails with `pg  1.0`. Downgrading pg gem to the previous most stable version `0.21` should work for you. Just try

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it did indeed help me ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Please try to remove this one:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

`pg` gem has already defined in outer scope so that it doesn't need to define in `production` group. Also please start server with `bundle exec rails s` to run rails server in current context of `Gemfile`.

Comment: Just to add to this - the same code exists duping the `pg` gem in the Gemfile's development and development / test groups...

Answer (score 1):

Just keep the first occurence of `gem 'pg'` at the top of your Gemfile. All others should go away.

Then start your application with `bundle exec rails s` as stated before.

Should then work.

Comment: Still saying the gem isn't loaded :(

Comment: can you give some background: Which OS,which database version, current Gemfile with version of pg gem and the current database yaml. just update your question.

Comment: Did you run bundle install to install all required gems?

Comment: Yes, i'll update the question now. Current yaml and gemfile are posted in the question already :)